# Como desenvolver um Auto Text Expander com JavaScript ou jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Desejo criar várias palavras-chaves para funcionarem como atalho para auto completar.

```
"oi." daria "Olá Amigo"

"ate." daria "Abraço e até mais"
```

Por exemplo, eu digito num textarea do meu site a palavra "teste." e automaticamente e imediatamente este atalho vira a frase "completa minha frase teste" e conforme vou digitando mais atalhos que dão "match" tudo vai se auto completando.

Tem uma extensão do Chrome que faz isso, porém desejo desenvolver com JS para fazer esta funcionalidade dentro do meu site. Desta forma você consegue escrever um texto gigante num textarea para enviar como mensagem, economizando tempo.

[Clique aqui](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-text-expander-for-go/iibninhmiggehlcdolcilmhacighjamp?hl=pt-BR) e veja a extensão que estou falando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é simples, tens de ter um objeto com as versões curtas e longas de cada frase e depois usar algo assim:

```js
var atalhos = {
  'oi.': 'Olá Amigo',
  'ate.': 'Abraço e até mais'
}

var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
textarea.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  for (var chave in atalhos) {
    // substituir caso haja algum match
    var _chave = chave.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');
    var regex = new RegExp('(^)' + _chave + '|(\\s)' + _chave);
    var match = textarea.value.match(regex);
    if (!match) continue;
    match = match.filter(function(m){return typeof m !== 'undefined';});
    textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(regex, match[1] + atalhos[chave]);
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```